# javascript overriding current methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, overriding, arcgis

I am using javascript API and I want to add some features or override api features. For example http://js.arcgis.com/3.6/ is Arcgis javascript API. I am using this like this.

```
  require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
    map = new Map("map", { basemap: "topo"});
  });

{ basemap: "topo"} is options of map.
```

I opened the url(http://js.arcgis.com/3.6/) from browser and I see the basemaps like this.

```
basemaps:{
             "streets":
             {
                 title:"Streets",
                 baseMapLayers:[{url:"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"}]
             },
             "topo":
             {
                 title:"Topographic",
                 baseMapLayers:[{url:"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"}]
             }
        }
```

My question is how can I add a new basemap on **basemaps** in API? Can I override it? Like following.

```
basemaps:{
             "streets":
             {
                 title:"Streets",
                 baseMapLayers:[{url:"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"}]
             },
             "topo":
             {
                 title:"Topographic",
                 baseMapLayers:[{url:"http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer"}]
             },
             "mymap":
             {
                 title:"MyCustomImageMap",
                 baseMapLayers:[{url:"http://mydomain.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/myworld/MapServer"}]
             }
        }
```

I have learned the prototype for functions while learning javscript but I can not do anything in this stuation. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [BaseMap](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/basemap-amd.html) or [BasemapLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/basemaplayer-amd.html) to do this. You not need override something.